# Find the digits $A,B,C$ such that $ABC+BAC+CAB=ABBC$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

A,B,C are distinct digits of a three digit number such that

```
                         A B C
                         B A C
                      +  C A B
                     ____________
                        A B B C
```

Find the value of A+B+C.

a) 16 b) 17 c) 18 d) 19

I tried it out by using the digits 16 17 18 19 by breaking them in three numbers but due to so large number of ways of breaking I cannot help my cause.

Comment: Just quickly, notice that the final column has $A+B+C$ so since each of these digits lie in $0-9$, then the most the carry could have been is $2$. So you know that one of the following is true: $A+B+C+2=A$, $A+B+C+1=A$, $A+B+C=A$. But $A+B+C=A$ isn't possible because then $B+C=0$ forcing $B=C=0$, which clearly isn't the case. Then you have two cases left to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The largest possible carry from a sum of three digits is $2$, so from the righthand column we see that $2C+B$ is $C$, $10+C$, or $20+C$, and therefore $C+B$ is $0$, $10$, or $20$. The sum of two distinct digits cannot be $0$ or $20$, so $C+B=10$, and there is a carry of $1$ to the middle column.

From the middle column we then see that $B+2A+1$ is $B$, $10+B$, or $20+B$, so that $2A+1$ is $0$, $10$, or $20$. But all of these are impossible since $2A+1$ is clearly odd. Thus, the problem has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

$ABC+BAC+CAB=ABBC \\
C+10B+100A+C+10A+100B+B+10A+100C=C+110B+1000A$

and this yields to  $B+C=880A-100C$,
and this in turn implies the number 20 divides $B+C$. But $B$ and $C$ are digits. So $2\leq{B+C}\leq18$. Clearly a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* I just realized this question was asked over a year ago, my bad.

I assume that the question was a typo, at least I hope it was.

```
                           A B C
                           B C A
                           C A B
                        ___________

                         A B B C
```

instead of

```
                           A B C
                           B A C
                           C A B
                        ___________

                         A B B C
```

In this case, we have the easy problem:

$$111(A+B+C)=1000A+110B+C$$

We want $1000A+110B+C$ to be divisible by $111$, and that is just a matter of trial and error. The result is $A+B+C=18$.

Comment: This man not only sees the problems answer, but also how the question is wrong. This man deserves some more points.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering the edited question without trial and error method as it will consume more time. we can see that A+B must be 10 as C added to it will result in C in the right most digit and the carry will be 1(carry cannot be 2 as A+B cannot be 20,as they r single digit number).now for the middle column B+C+A+1(i.e carry)=B is possible if A+C=9. then A+B+C+1=AB(i.e 10A+B). 
A+B=10;
A+C=9;
therefore, A+B+C+1=(A+C+1)+B=10+B.
so 10+B=10A+B; therefore, A=1;
similiarly B=9,C=8.
so,A+B+C=18

Answer (score 0):

Let, $A=1, B=2, C=3$

The digit $A$ has $3$ times $=1\cdot 3=3$

The digit $B$ has $3$ times$=2\cdot 3=6$

The digit $C$ has $3$ times $=3\cdot 3=9$
Now:

$A+B+C=3+6+9=18$